# Zend Server 8 PDO could not find driver via CLI

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, zend-server

I installed Zend Server 8, and I need to run scripts that use MySQL via the command line.

I get this error when I run one of my CLI scripts:

```
 PDOException
 could not find driver
```

But everything works via http, problem only occurs in CLI. I know there is a different `php.ini` for the CLI. However, when i reference the  `php.ini` that the server uses for http like this:

```
php -c/usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini my-script
```

I get this:

```
    Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 

    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/pdo.so' - 
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/pdo.so: 
    cannot open shared object file: 
    No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/readline.so' - /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/readline.so: 
cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php on line 155
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. I use `Ubuntu 14.04` if that makes a difference.

It might also be useful to say that I installed LAMP first like this:
`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` and then I installed `Zend Server`

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just changing the `php` alias to the `php` that was installed by `Zend Server` like this:

`alias php=/usr/local/zend/bin/php`

This seems to work, but still looking for a better/proper solution.

Comment: This is the correct solution, Teodore.  When working in the Zend Server environment you should always use the php executable they provide.  As you discovered, it will always use the php.ini file that ships with zend server which means that what you update directives and component configurations via Zend Server, those changes will be written to the correct php.ini file and reflected as soon as you restart Zend Server. It also allows you to use the Zend Debugger (auto-attached to their own executables but not the system-default ones) and Z-Ray with Zend Studio integration...

Comment: Thanks for confirming :)